# why i can my App not starting or see over App menu?

Tags: android

I have a problem.
I have a signed apk generated and installed but
I can't start the App from installing and I can't see it in the app menu.
I can only see it in the settings app menu.
Why cant I see it or starting?
The app can be started via the debugger.
Can you help me?

The operating system is Android 7 and 5.

Here is my manifesto:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.xxxxxx"
android:versionCode="12"
android:versionName="4.0.0">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="true" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<application
    android:name="com.control.xxxx.xxxxx"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:persistent="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!-- Activities -->
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ScannerActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_qrcode_scanner"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".HelpActivity"
        android:label="@string/help_title"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.control.installation.ConfigActivity"
        android:label="@string/install_title"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".CameraHideActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_camera_hide"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ProjectListActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_project_list"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.control.camerahidetexts.CamHideConfiguratorActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_config_hideactivity"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.control.personalmessages.PersMsgActivity"
        android:label="@string/pm_title"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.control.language.LanguageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_languageactivity"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog" />

    <activity
        android:name=".ButtonActivity"
        android:label="@string/button_settings"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" />

    <!-- Receivers -->
    <receiver android:name="com.control.personalmessages.PersMsgReceiver" />
    <receiver android:name="com.control.broadcastreceiver.AppRestartReceiver" />
    <receiver android:name="com.control.camerahidetexts.CamHideConfigTextsReceiver" />
    <receiver android:name="com.control.livepackets.LivepaketReceiver" />
    <receiver android:name="com.control.projecttransponderlists.ListUpdateReceiver" />
    <receiver android:name="com.control.timestamps.TimestampReceiver" />
    <receiver android:name="com.control.projecttransponderlists.ListUpdateDoneReceiver" />
    <receiver android:name="com.control.log.LogReceiver" />
    <receiver android:name="com.control.broadcastreceiver.BootUpReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- Services -->
    <service android:name="com.control.personalmessages.SetPersonalMessagesToReadService" />
    <service android:name="com.control.personalmessages.DownloadPersMsgService" />
    <service android:name="com.control.personalmessages.FinishPMDownloadService" />
    <service android:name="com.control.camerahidetexts.CamHideConfigTextsService" />
    <service android:name="com.control.projecttransponderlists.ProjectListService" />
    <service android:name="com.control.projecttransponderlists.TransponderListService" />
    <service android:name="com.control.projecttransponderlists.LinkTransponderProjectListService" />
    <service android:name="com.control.projecttransponderlists.ListUpdateService" />
    <service android:name="com.control.projecttransponderlists.ListUpdateDoneService" />
    <service android:name="com.control.timestamps.TimestampService" />
    <service android:name="com.control.log.LogSendService" />
    <service android:name="com.control.livepackets.LivepaketService" />

</application>
```

**Update**
i found the problem, it was android:mimeType but why?
Can you explain it to me?

Comment: share your manifest.xml file

Comment: Confirm that you have a launcher activity specified in Manifest.xml file.

Comment: Please, my manifest.

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot launch mode. Write this in your AndroidManifest.xml inside application element

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

replace .MainActivity with your activity name

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
My app has this entry in the manifest.
It may be that I have made a mistake.